# I am unable to install latest version of R

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, r

I am trying to install the latest version of R into Ubuntu 16.04.

But somehow it installs 3.4.4 even though latest version of R is 3.6.1. I have also read some articles that state *"To obtain the latest R 3.6 packages, add an entry like"*:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu disco-cran35/
```

But still I don't understand what should I do with this link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, remove the installed version of R using:

```
sudo apt purge r-base
```

You should also uninstall any other R packages that you may have installed.

As stated in the [R installation guide](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html), for 16.04 you need to add the repository `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. There is a **longer** and a **shorter** way to do this.

**Longer way:**

1. To add the repository open a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Copy and paste `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/` at the end of the file (paste is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for `nano`).
3. Then add the public key for the repository running the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
   ```
4. Finally, update your system to enable the repository:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

**Shorter way:**

You can add the repository, key and update as a *one-line terminal command*:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list' && sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 && sudo apt update
```

Whichever way you selected, you should be able to install R 3.6 by running:

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using the **ropenblas** package from R. Install the **devtools** package and then run the following code:

```
devtools::install_github(repo = "prdm0/ropenblas", force = TRUE)
ropenblas::rcompiler()
```

See: 
https://github.com/prdm0/ropenblas#rcompiler-function

Yes, you with **ropenblas** will be able to compile the latest stable version of the R language. **R** and **Rscript** binaries will be created and configured for use in your GNU/Linux distribution.  The procedure is the same for any GNU/Linux distribution.